# How to change the datetime value to year only, that retrieve from database table and show on combobox.display member?

Tags: oledb, vb.net-2010

i got a list of datetime value from ()table look like these: 
31/12/14 4:45:30 PM
                                           31/12/14 4:45:30 PM

31/12/14 4:45:30 PM

31/12/14 4:45:30 PM

31/12/14 4:45:30 PM

AND i want them to only show like e.g.:, in the combobox.display member 

2014
2015
2016
 
2017

**i know i wrote like below might have datatypes error, but anyone can correct me or guide me on this??**

```vb
Public Sub combothing()
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & aaa & "';Persist Security Info=False;")
    Dim selectme As String = "SELECT * FROM yeartbl"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(selectme, connection)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds)
        da.Fill(ds, "yeartbl")
        dt = ds.Tables("yeartbl")
        connection.Close()
        Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "YID"
        **Convert.ToDateTime(Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Years").Date.Year.ToString()**
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you connecting to, excel file?

Comment: just connection and retrieve datetime value from access database

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that you can do (assuming we work against Excel) is, when you already filled `DataSet`, add one more column

```vb
ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("year", System.Type.GetType("System.Integer"))

For each (r as row in ds.Tables(0).Rows)
    r("year") = DirectCast(r("YTD"), DateTime).Year 'assuming it is not null column
Next
```

Now, set Value Member to

```
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Year"
```

Also, needs more research, you may can do this:

```
 "SELECT *, FunctionTOConvertToDate(YTD) as year FROM yeartbl"
```

Comment: will try this now, TQ~!

Comment: not understand ds.table(0).columns.add("",.......) what should declare in this (,........)? need explanation?

Comment: @廖伟Donald Did you see my updated code? Also, try this `SELECT Year(YTD) FROM yeartbl`. If this runs - it is crazy good. I just doubt though that it will, without running it from MS Access application